# Most sold products in shop transactions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a query to select the most sold products given the number of top products to fetch and the language code. I don't know to do it right so I would appreciate you help.

```
shop_transactions
id
1
2
3

shop_transaction_products_match
id | shop_transaction_id | product_id | units_bought
1    1                     1            4
2    2                     2            1
3    3                     2            2


products_translations
id | product_id | language_code | name | seo_name
1    1            es              Hola   hola
2    1            en              Hey u  hey-u
3    2            es              Adiós  adios
4    2            en              Bye u  bye-u

products
id | category_id
1    1
2    2

product_categories
id
1
2

product_categories_translations
id | category_id | language_code | name | seo_name
1    1             es              AA     aa
2    1             en              BB     bb
3    2             es              CC     cc
4    3             en              DD     dd
```

The information per row is: name from product_translations, seo_name from product_translations, name from product_categories_translations, seo_name from product_categories_translations

Rows ordered descendant by number products sold in total.

Considering the example information, the result if number of products to fetch is 2 and the language is es, would be:

Hola, hola, AA, aa -> 4 units sold of this product

Adiós, adios, CC, cc -> 3 units sold of this product

Thank you!

Edit:

The code I tried so far... and I am missing some things that I dont know how to do it:

```
SELECT pt.name, pt.seo_name, pct.name as name_category, pct.seo_name as seo_name_category
                                  From product_translations pt, products p, product_categories pc, product_categories_translations pct
                                  where p.id in (Select product_id from shop_transaction_product_match where shop_transaction_id in
                                  (Select id from shop_transactions)) AND pt.language_code = :language_code AND pct.language_code = :language_code
                                  AND p.category_id = pct.category_id
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try add a section of code so we can help see where you are perhaps misguided.

Comment: yeah I did buy I'm missing a lot:

`SELECT pt.name, pt.seo_name, pct.seo_name as seo_name_category
                                      From product_translations pt, products p, product_categories pc, product_categories_translations pct
                                      where p.id in (Select product_id from shop_transaction_product_match where shop_transaction_id in 
                                      (Select id from shop_transactions)) AND pt.language_code = :language_code AND pct.language_code = :language_code
                                      AND p.category_id = pct.category_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 pt.name, pt.seo_name, pct.name, pct.seo_name,
 SUM(stpm.units_bought) units_sold
FROM products AS p
 LEFT JOIN product_categories AS pc ON p.category_id = pc.id
 LEFT JOIN products_translations AS pt ON p.id = pt.product_id AND pt.language_code = 'es'
 LEFT JOIN product_categories_translations AS pct ON pc.id = pct.category_id AND pct.language_code = 'es'
 LEFT JOIN shop_transaction_products_match AS stpm ON p.id = stpm.product_id
-- Where p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY units_sold DESC
limit 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect but I had to edit two things:

Instead of `ORDER BY stpm.units_bought DESC` is `ORDER BY units_sold DESC` and I added after DESC `Limit 2`

Thanks!

Comment: I accept your answer because, for some reason, the query is faster than @subin-c-poonamgode answer.

Thanks both of you

Comment: `Left join` faster than `inner join`, isn't it ? @subin-c-poonamgode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `IN` it is better to use `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT products_translations.name,
           products_translations.seo_name,
           product_categories_translations.name,
           product_categories_translations.seo_name,
           SUM(shop_transaction_products_match.units_bought) AS Product_count
    FROM
         shop_transactions 
    INNER JOIN 
         shop_transaction_products_match
    ON shop_transactions.id=shop_transaction_products_match.shop_transaction_id
    INNER JOIN 
         products_translations 
    ON products_translations.product_id = shop_transaction_products_match.product_id
    INNER JOIN 
         products 
    ON products.id = shop_transaction_products_match.product_id
    INNER JOIN
        product_categories 
    ON products.category_id = product_categories.id
    INNER JOIN
        product_categories_translations
    ON product_categories_translations.category_id = product_categories.id AND product_categories_translations.language_code = products_translations.language_code 
    WHERE products_translations.language_code= 'es' GROUP BY products.id
    Limit 2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, it helps but it is not showing me the data information I am looking for.

I need to consider the units_bought of the product in each shop transaction, and I do not provide the product_id, I provide the number of product to retrieve.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry man, I pressed enter, and the comment went though... I edited my comment

Comment: There were two errors:

`ON shop_transactions.id=shop_transactions.shop_transaction_id` 

should be 

`ON shop_transactions.id=shop_transaction_products_match.shop_transaction_id` 

And 

`WHERE 
    products.id = 2 AND products_translations.language_code= 'es'
    GROUP BY products.id`

Should be

` WHERE 
   products_translations.language_code= 'es'
    GROUP BY products.id Limit 2`

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Edit your answer to valid it

Comment: Not working: 1 two Where key words together, 2 Missing Limit, and 3 Group by Product_count

Comment: I didnt get the `Group by Product_count`

Comment: I just saw I had a mistake in my answer. It was group by products.id Order by Product_count DESC Limit 2